# Why is Cocoapods complaining about the embedded content contains swift setting in the build settings?

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods

I recently added swift files to my test target (combined with older cocoa touch classes).

Why is cocoapods complaining about the embedded content contains swift setting in the build settings?

> [!] The YOURP-PROJECT-Tests [Debug] target overrides the
>   EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT build setting defined in
>   Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods-YOUR-PROJECT-Tests/Pods-YOUR-PROJECT-Tests.debug.xcconfig.
>   This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I needed to add the $(inherited) flag to the build setting

[image]

Comment: This is how to silent the warning. However I'm more curious about why it is complaining. There are threads about ITC issue with this flag enabled. So normally I'd like to have full control on it and to keep it false. Solution suggested at [CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4515) is to ignore this warning for now.

Comment: What does it inherit from? There's no setting in the Project be default. Yet, it says yes.

Comment: I don't have this option in my build options, do you know how to add it?

Comment: Turns out that I had the correct project but the wrong target. Show the list of targets by pressing this: http://s16.postimg.org/4uiuhid05/Screen_Shot_2016_09_20_at_21_38_04.png

Comment: For those who don't know how to add click on "Other" while displaying Yes/No options. Then add $(inherited).

Comment: The screenshot above shows it as "Yes - $(inherited)", but when I add "$(inherited)" it switched to "No - $(inherited)". Anybody else have the same thing?

Answer (score 7):

If you replace YES with "$(inherited)" it will fix the issue in the project/target EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT value. After you click Enter it will show a "YES". Run the pod install again and the issue should disappear.