# App targets override the `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` build setting defined in Pods.xcconfig

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a confusing warning that likely has a simple solution that I'm overlooking. When I run `pod install` in the terminal, I get these warnings:

> [!] The `Ripelist [Debug]` target overrides the `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
>       - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or - Remove the build settings from the target.
>
> [!] The `Ripelist [Release]` target overrides the `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
>       - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
>       - Remove the build settings from the target.

Here's where I get confused.

My Pods xcconfig file is shown below where you can see that the setting for `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` is set to "Yes" (debug and release xcconfigs are exactly the same settings so I only included one screenshot for both):

[image: Pods.debug.xcconfig]

Now here are my settings that are apparently "overriding" the defined setting you just saw (project, target and test target):

[image: project setting]
[image: app target setting]
[image: app test target setting]

The warning message says to use the `$(inherited)` flag but there's no place to add $(inherited) because it's basically a dropdown bool with only the options "Yes" and "No". Along with that, the second option the warning recommends is to "remove the build settings from the target". I can't remove Yes or No. If you look below there's no option to remove either one:

[image]

If I click "other..." and remove the text, it automatically goes back to "Yes". If I click "other..." and type in $(inherited) then it just goes to "No - $(inherited)".

Can someone tell me how to eliminate these warnings?

Comment: Sometimes using pods is more complicated than just importing and mainiting frameworks manually.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you find the solution for it?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34445636/why-is-cocoapods-complaining-about-the-embedded-content-contains-swift-setting-i

Comment: Did you find a solution? Updating to Xcode 8 has given me similar problems.

Comment: @Questioner Honestly this was too long ago I forgot if I figured it out or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to select "other" from the dropdown, then add `$(inherited)` there. It deducted what it needed from that.