# EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT in Xcode and Cocoapods warning

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

We are having a mix of Objective C and Swift into our in-house framework. This requires me to select

> EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES

in the project Build Setting. Without setting this property, Xcode is throwing runtime error

```
Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
```

But if I set

> EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES

`Cocoapod` Pod Init is throwing warning

```
target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-AK/Pods-AK.debug.xcconfig
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Cocoapods complaining about the embedded content contains swift setting in the build settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34445636/why-is-cocoapods-complaining-about-the-embedded-content-contains-swift-setting-i)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. I know that setting 'No' or '$Inherited' to ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES will solve the CocoaPod issue. But I get runtime error 'Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib'

Answer (score 0):

Go to project main target (which target build the whole application)

1. Search for `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES`
2. Set it's value to `$(inherited)` by selecting the `other` option.

Hope this resolve the issue.

Comment: Any value other than 'Yes' to ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES will crash during runtime. Like I said before I get error 'Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib'

Comment: yes itt will crash at runtime if embeded framework contains swift, and cocoapod will set this $inherited to yes based on that. if OP uses only obj-c pods its unnecessary to copying this swift library.